# item icon won't display after choosing the item

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

i am using [this](https://github.com/Kwasow/BottomNavigationCircles-Android) library to make the same bottom navigation but when i click on item the icon will disappear, here is my code

activity_main:

```
<com.github.kwasow.bottomnavigationcircles.BottomNavigationCircles
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="true"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

navigation items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/destination_ejournal"
    android:icon="@drawable/ejournal_selector"

    android:title="@string/bottomnav_ejournal" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/destination_solah"
    android:icon="@drawable/solah_selector"
    android:title="@string/bottomnav_solah" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/destination_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_selector"
    android:title="@string/bottomnav_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/destination_dua"
    android:icon="@drawable/dua_selector"
    android:title="@string/bottomnav_dua" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/more_selector"
    android:title="@string/bottomnav_more" />
```

MainActivity:

```
val bottomNavigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationCircles>(R.id.navigation)
    bottomNavigation.color = Color.WHITE
```

so what am i doing wrong here?

is it in the activity or XML?

Images of the problem:

[If i click Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAOsd.png)

[If i navigate to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6IaY.png)

[If i change color from white to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qBkT.png)

home selector:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home" android:state_checked="false" />

</selector>
```

ic_home: is verctor
home_selected: is png

**SOLUTION:**

**i was using a selector to display a different drawable if the "state_checked" and one of them was PNG format so it didn't appear, i used 2 vectors for the selector and it works fine now**

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried  your example with that library & the problem is that you're setting the color to white at runtime & that kind of blends into the bottomnav color.

You can try different color e.g red.

```
val bottomNavigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationCircles>(R.id.navigation)
bottomNavigation.color = Color.RED
```

It gives me following result:

[image: botton nav]

Comment: i edited my question, if i set another color there will be a circle red only

Comment: @Enigma That looks like some problem with  `drawable`  Can you please post sample code for one of the drawable? let's say `home_selector`

Comment: i have added it

Comment: @Enigma With my own images, it works for me. Can you please share your drawables?  `home_selected` & `ic_home`

Comment: i found the problem, looks like i can't use PNG in that selector and this library, when i used 2 vectors it worked fine, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Enigma That's what i thought. Great that you resolved it :)